# execute a javascript function for ten times

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

i have writed this code but not work, can you help me?

```
<a href="#" id="add">Aggiungi</a><br>
<script>
var i=0;
if (i<=10){
    var count = 0; 
    $(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(){
            count += 1;
            //alert(i);
            $('#container').append('<input id="url_' + count + '" name="url_' + count + '" type="input" value="http://" size="35" />' );
            i++; });
    });
}

</script> 
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: the <br> at the end of each line will give an error

Comment: I suspect those were put in to keep SO from wrapping, not in the original script.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: As you are a new user, I want to welcome you to stackoverflow, your personal debugging service.

Comment: What output do you expecting from this code?

Comment: I need to display video at a maximum of 10 input fields, but the script if I delete the field if (i <10) displays endless fields, and if I leave it such as it does not display anything

Comment: thanks simonzack!! =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want restrict only 10 input container .
Try this

```
 <a href="#" id="add">Aggiungi</a><br>
 <script>
  var i = 0;
  var count = 0;
  $(function () {
     $('#add').click(function () {
        if ($('*[id^=url]').length < 10) {
            $('#container').append('<input id="url_' + count + '" name="url_' + count + '" type="input" value="http://" size="35" /><br>');
            i++;
         }
      });
   });    
 </script>
```

Comment: i love you!! by all night I'm looking for a solution tnks!!

Comment: @user3004586 Actually whenever you click on add button the debugger hits hits inside the add click function not outside .So you have to put the condition inside the click function not outside and please accept the answer if it helps you thankx...:)